# Tab with swipe using pagerslidingtabstrip getting class cast exception

Tags: android, tabs, swipe, pagerslidingtabstrip

Can any one help me out to integrate pagerslidingtabstrip (Tab with swipe) in android 
i am getting

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip cannot be cast to com.*.*.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    // Give the PagerSlidingTabStrip the ViewPager
    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabsStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    // Attach the view pager to the tab strip
    tabsStrip.setViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you provide examples of code you've put together after following a tutorial and any errors/unexpected behaviors you see?

Comment: Hi Tom, I am not able integrate it , I downloaded the example but Glader is not able to install...  When i create a project two folder is created app and Glader..

Comment: i use https://guides.codepath.com/android/Sliding-Tabs-with-PagerSlidingTabStrip but dont understand where dependencies {
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
} should put and what lib need to be added

Comment: The document specifies app/build.gradle, do you have a build.gradle file?

Comment: yes actually i facing issue on PagerSlidingTabStrip tabsStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);  where PagerSlidingTabStrip  is not resolved "Cannot Resolved the symbol"  it seems some liabrary is missing.... any idea

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't something I've had experience with, but if you update your question with those specifics, someone should be able to lend a hand :)

Comment: yes i will... actually thanks to you as i moved 1 step ahead and getting excception of  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip cannot be cast to com.kids.test.PagerSlidingTabStrip